# XSL sum() and variable/loop

Tags: xslt, sum, matching, addition

I have been trying to figure out why my variable assigned sum isn't working, also my table output is repeating only the first element through out the whole table. What i am trying to get this code to do is get the studentID of each student printed in the first column, the student name of that ID in the second column, and then assign a variable that holds the students total mark of the 3 assessments they have completed to print their total mark in the third column, followed by as assignment of HD, D, C, P, or F as based on their total mark e.g. HD is 85 plus and D is 75+ but not higher than 84. etc.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I am still new to XML/XSL so criticism is welcome.

grade.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:variable name="StudentAmount" select="count(document('AssessmentItems.xml')/assessmentList/unit/studentList/student)"/>
    <xsl:variable name="totalmark" select="sum(document('AssessmentItems.xml')/assessmentList/unit/*
    [//assessmentList/unit/assessmentItems/assessment/@studId = //assessmentList/unit/studentList/student/@sid])"/>

  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Grade Report for <xsl:value-of select="assessmentList/unit/@unitId"/> - <xsl:value-of select="assessmentList/unit/unitName"/></h2>
    <p>Number of students in this unit: <xsl:value-of select="$StudentAmount"/></p>

    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Total Mark</th>
        <th>Grade</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="assessmentList/unit/studentList/student">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="document('AssessmentItems.xml')/assessmentList/unit/studentList/student/@sid"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="document('AssessmentItems.xml')/assessmentList/unit/studentList/student"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="document('AssessmentItems.xml')/assessmentList/unit/assessmentItems/assessment/mark"/></td>

        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$totalmark &gt; 85">
        <td color="blue">HD</td>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$totalmark &gt; 75">
        <td color="black">D</td>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$totalmark &gt; 65">
        <td color="black">C</td>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="$totalmark &gt; 50">
        <td color="black">P</td>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
        <td color="red">F</td>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>

      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>

    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the file AssessmentItems.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="grade.xsl"?>
<assessmentList>
    <unit unitId="3311">
        <unitName>Learn To Read</unitName>
        <studentList>
            <student sid="1001">Lisa Simpson</student>
            <student sid="1002">Barney Rubble</student>
            <student sid="1003">Donald Duck</student>
        </studentList>
        <assessmentItems>
            <assessment name="Assignment 1" weight="20">
                <mark studId="1001">12</mark>
                <mark studId="1002">18</mark>
                <mark studId="1003">9</mark>
            </assessment>
            <assessment name="Assignment 2" weight="25">
                <mark studId="1001">23</mark>
                <mark studId="1002">14</mark>
                <mark studId="1003">12.5</mark>
            </assessment>
            <assessment name="Quiz" weight="15">
                <mark studId="1001">13</mark>
                <mark studId="1002">9</mark>
                <mark studId="1003">6</mark>
            </assessment>
            <assessment name="Final Exam" weight="40">
                <mark studId="1001">38</mark>
                <mark studId="1002">21</mark>
                <mark studId="1003">20.5</mark>
            </assessment>
        </assessmentItems>
    </unit>
</assessmentList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, because you are only working on a single XML document, you don't need the constant references to document('AssessmentItems.xml') at all. So, for example

```
<xsl:value-of 
   select="document('AssessmentItems.xml')/assessmentList/unit/studentList/student/@sid"/>
```

Can be replaced with just

```
<xsl:value-of select="/assessmentList/unit/studentList/student/@sid"/>
```

This leads on to the second problem. The xpath above is relative to the document element of the XML and will return the @sid of the very first student it finds, and no the @sid of the student you are currently positioned on. You can simply do this in your case

```
<xsl:value-of select="@sid"/>
```

Another issue is that you define the variable **totalmarks** at the top of the XSLT, when in fact it should be defined within the scope of your **xsl:for-each** so that it is specific for the current student

```
<xsl:variable name="totalmark" select="sum(../../assessmentItems/assessment/mark[@studId = current()/@sid])" />
```

Actually, it may be better to make use of a key here, to look up the results

```
<xsl:key name="marks" match="mark" use="@studId" />
```

And to get the total results for a student....

```
 <xsl:variable name="totalmark" select="sum(key('marks', @sid))" />
```

One final comment, although not a problem, it is often better to use **xsl:apply-templates** rather than **xsl:for-each** as this avoids excessive indentation, and allows better code re-use.

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:key name="marks" match="mark" use="@studId"/>

   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="StudentAmount" select="count(/assessmentList/unit/studentList/student)"/>
      <html>
         <body>
            <h2>Grade Report for 
               <xsl:value-of select="assessmentList/unit/@unitId"/>- 
               <xsl:value-of select="assessmentList/unit/unitName"/>
            </h2>
            <p>Number of students in this unit: 
               <xsl:value-of select="$StudentAmount"/></p>
            <table border="1">
               <tr>
                  <th>ID</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Total Mark</th>
                  <th>Grade</th>
               </tr>
               <xsl:apply-templates select="assessmentList/unit/studentList/student"/>
            </table>
         </body>
      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="student">
      <xsl:variable name="totalmark" select="sum(key('marks', @sid))"/>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="@sid"/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </td>
         <td>
            <xsl:value-of select="$totalmark"/>
         </td>
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$totalmark &gt; 85">
               <td color="blue">HD</td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$totalmark &gt; 75">
               <td color="black">D</td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$totalmark &gt; 65">
               <td color="black">C</td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$totalmark &gt; 50">
               <td color="black">P</td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
               <td color="red">F</td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
      </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following HTML is output

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>Grade Report for 3311- Learn To Read</h2>
      <p>Number of students in this unit: 3</p>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Total Mark</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1001</td>
            <td>Lisa Simpson</td>
            <td>86</td>
            <td color="blue">HD</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1002</td>
            <td>Barney Rubble</td>
            <td>62</td>
            <td color="black">P</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>1003</td>
            <td>Donald Duck</td>
            <td>48</td>
            <td color="red">F</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Do note this assumes only one **unit** element in your XML. If your actual XML have multiple units, and you wanted a separate table for each, then this is not a problem, you would just need to make sure the unit id is part of the **xsl:key** so you can look up results for a given student in a given unit.

Comment: I see the error in my ways! Thank you so much for your help Tim C! And yes what I am going to attempt now is getting the apply-templates version of this code to work, I like to get a set of code working before I attempt to make a new version of it with the better features, just for my own knowledges sake. Is there any documentation that you yourself prefer other than the w3 schools xsl section on apply-templates?

Answer (score 0):

A very quick glance at your code reveals that the predicate

```
[//assessmentList/unit/assessmentItems/assessment/@studId = //assessmentList/unit/studentList/student/@sid]
```

is obviously wrong, because it has the same value (either true or false) for every element in your source document.

Correcting it requires more study of the problem than I have time for. But you seem to have fallen victim to the "if it doesn't work then put '//' at the front" fallacy.